# How to access the processed dataset after nest() function in D3 V4?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm totally new in D3.js. Right now I stumbled upon an issue related to nest() of the library.

Below is my code for nest() in D3 v4. Note that I'm finding the mean of time_in_hospital. The problem is the var `check` doesn't give the data that I want.

```
var groupByAgeAndtime = d3.nest()
              .key(function(d) { return d.age; })
              .rollup(function(v) { return d3.mean(v, function(d) { return d.time_in_hospital; }); })
              .object(datapoints);//specify the dataset used

    var check = d3.min(groupByAgeAndtime, function(d){
        return d.time_in_hospital;
    });
    console.log(groupByAgeAndtime);
    console.log(check);
```

The mean in the square area inside the screenshot is the data that I want to get by var `check`.

[image]

And in the screenshot, why var `check` is undefined?

Comment: Welcome to stackOverflow.

`d3.min` should be passed an array as first parameter ([source](https://github.com/d3/d3-array#min)), but according to the screenshot you posted, `groupByAgeAndTime` is an object.

Also, `groupByAgeAndTime` does not have a `time_in_hospital` property.

Fixing these should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`check` is `undefined` because [d3.min](https://github.com/d3/d3-array#min) requires an array to be passed to return back the minimum value.

> **d3.min:** Returns the minimum value in the given **array** using natural order

As you've computed `groupByAgeAndTime` correctly, you can just pass the keys to `d3.min` and get the min value of that. Here's your code with an example dataset:

```js
var datapoints = [
 {age: '0-10', time_in_hospital: 20},
 {age: '10-20', time_in_hospital: 60},
 {age: '20-30', time_in_hospital: 12},
 {age: '30-40', time_in_hospital: 34},
 {age: '0-10', time_in_hospital: 3},
 {age: '10-20', time_in_hospital: 5},
 {age: '20-30', time_in_hospital: 10},  
];

var groupByAgeAndtime = d3.nest()
 .key(function (d) { return d.age; })
  .rollup(function(v) { return d3.mean(v, function(d) { return d.time_in_hospital; }); })
  .object(datapoints);//specify the dataset used
  
var check = d3.min(Object.keys(groupByAgeAndtime), function(d){
  return groupByAgeAndtime[d];
});
console.log(groupByAgeAndtime);
console.log(check);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: BTW, what does keys() doing actually? Is it accessing the specific array inside the object?

Comment: Sure. Glad I could help. `Object.keys()` returns an array of an object's own property "names". Refer [docs for simple examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys). In your case, `Object.keys` would give out all the age groups that result out of `d3.nest()` and then `d3.min` gives out the minimum of those. Try console logging within the `d3.min`.